# creating executables from labview for Linux based platofrm

Tags: labview

can we create executables for beaglebone black micrcontroller which is a linux based platform having arm processor using labview?If yes,How?

Comment: There are tons of articles. I think you did not research even! I am posting the first two results of google search and they answer to your question: http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/LINX-3-0-LabVIEW-for-BeagleBone-Black-and-Raspberry-Pi-2-3/td-p/3278758 http://hackerboards.com/ni-labview-gains-raspberry-pi-and-beaglebone-black-support/

Comment: http://hackerboards.com/ni-labview-gains-raspberry-pi-and-beaglebone-black-support/

Comment: You should consider removing the question

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible using LINX add on for Labview.
[Here](https://www.labviewmakerhub.com/doku.php?id=learn:tutorials:libraries:linx:3-0) is how.

As already mentioned, it took 5 seconds to find the link searching Labview+Beaglebone with Duckduckgo.